# Bind - prioritize local domain over root

Tags: ubuntu, domain-name-system, bind

On Ubuntu Server 16.04, I have Bind running as the DNS server. Overall, it works rather well. The problem I'm having is when I just specify the name of a system on my network, it tries to reach out to the root zones (I assume) instead of looking locally first.

```
#/etc/resolv.conf
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 10.1.0.1
search priv
```

I have a resource called "zm". Here is what happens when I refer to it:

This is GOOD:

```
# dig zm.priv

; <<>> DiG 9.10.3-P4-Ubuntu <<>> zm.priv
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 29032
;; flags: qr aa rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 2

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;zm.priv.           IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
zm.priv.        604800  IN  A   10.18.0.31

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
priv.           604800  IN  NS  server.priv.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
server.priv.        604800  IN  A   10.1.0.1

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: ::1#53(::1)
;; WHEN: Tue May 01 18:08:17 EDT 2018
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 89
```

This is BAD:

```
# dig zm

; <<>> DiG 9.10.3-P4-Ubuntu <<>> zm
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 30620
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;zm.                IN  A

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
zm.         1157    IN  SOA ns1.zamnet.zm. hostmaster.nic.zm. 2018043020 21600 3600 604800 3600

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: ::1#53(::1)
;; WHEN: Tue May 01 18:09:32 EDT 2018
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 93
```

How do I make Bind assume my local domain ("priv") if I just enter a name of a resource WITHOUT it? I'm not sure I'm phrasing this right. But, if I type a single "word" as a network resource even if it is called "com" or "zm", I want the local address to come up like it did in the GOOD example above, not something from ns1.zamnet.zm.

Regards and thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not a `bind`/`named` issue. That's just the way `dig` behaves. You either want to use `nslookup` or `dig +search`. Consider applying `alias dig="dig +search"` to your shell.

Comment: I'm exasperated as to why dig behaves this way. I'm embarrassed to admit that it has probably racked up a few too many hours of unnecessary work and frustration over the past couple of years.

Comment: On the opposite I think it is totally the current default for `dig` to operate this way. it is a tool to primarily do DNS queries. Applications, using the OS resolvers in the libc will use the content of `/etc/resolv.conf` and its search list. So maybe you are not just doing the tests really needed based on your true initial problem.